# Can I add same document.createElement element on different element?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have 2 dropdown list to have same items.

This code is not working, when I create single element and tried to assign it to two different parent elements.

```
function addAssignee() {
    let dropDown1 = document.getElementById("bugOwner");
    let dropDown2 = document.getElementById("bugAssignee");

    document.getElementById("bugOwner").options.length = 0;
    document.getElementById("bugAssignee").options.length = 0;

    let localData = localStorage.getItem("users");
    let jsonObj = JSON.parse(localData);

    for (i in jsonObj.records) {
       let option = document.createElement("OPTION");
        option.innerHTML = jsonObj.records[i].name;
        option.value = jsonObj.records[i].unique;
        dropDown1.options.add(option);
        dropDown2.options.add(option);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

This code is working, when I create two elements, assign them values and add them to the parent element.

```
function addAssignee() {
    let dropDown1 = document.getElementById("bugOwner");
    let dropDown2 = document.getElementById("bugAssignee");

    document.getElementById("bugOwner").options.length = 0;
    document.getElementById("bugAssignee").options.length = 0;

    let localData = localStorage.getItem("users");
    let jsonObj = JSON.parse(localData);

    for (i in jsonObj.records) {
        let option1 = document.createElement("OPTION");
        let option2 = document.createElement("OPTION");
        option1.innerHTML = jsonObj.records[i].name;
        option1.value = jsonObj.records[i].unique;
        option2.innerHTML = jsonObj.records[i].name;
        option2.value = jsonObj.records[i].unique;
        dropDown1.options.add(option1);
        dropDown2.options.add(option2);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: can you share the html code?

Comment: <label for="bugOwner">Your Name</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="bugOwner" name="bugOwner">
            <option value="#">TODO Later</option>
        </select>
                
        <label for="bugAssignee">Bug Assignee</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="bugAssignee" name="bugAssignee">
            <option value="#">TODO Later</option>
        </select>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always do `let option2 = option1.clone()` or just clone at the time of appending: `dropDown2.options.add(option.clone())`

Comment: Set deep to true. dropDown2.options.add(option.clone(true))

Answer (score 1):

The HTML DOM model is constructed as a tree of Objects. Each DOM can have multiple children but **one and only one parent**. So even if there is no JavaScript error, you can't add the same DOM to different parents.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the children to have multiple parent. So create a `option` then clone it using `cloneNode`, `true` is for deep copy.

For this demo `localStorage` will not work , so harcoding the option
Also not if it is an array don use `for ..in` to loop over it. Use native `for` loop or array methods like `forEach`

```js
let jsonObj = {
  records: [{
    name: 'A',
    unique: '1'
  }, {
    name: 'B',
    unique: '10'
  }]
}


function addAssignee() {
  let dropDown1 = document.getElementById("bugOwner");
  let dropDown2 = document.getElementById("bugAssignee");

  document.getElementById("bugOwner").options.length = 0;
  document.getElementById("bugAssignee").options.length = 0;

  let options = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < jsonObj.records.length; i++) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = jsonObj.records[i].name;
    option.value = jsonObj.records[i].unique;
    let opt2 = option.cloneNode(true);
    dropDown1.options.add(option);
    dropDown2.options.add(opt2);
  }
}

addAssignee()
```

```html
<label for="bugOwner">Your Name</label>
<select class="form-control" id="bugOwner" name="bugOwner">
  <option value="#">TODO Later</option>
</select>

<label for="bugAssignee">Bug Assignee</label>
<select class="form-control" id="bugAssignee" name="bugAssignee">
  <option value="#">TODO Later</option>
</select>
```